# Performing a date comparison with a date field stored in the database

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, linq-to-sql

I am trying to compare todays date with a date in the database.
Todays date is saved in the database like this : 2016-06-14 00:00:00.000

dtTodaysDate is generated like this: 6/14/2016 11:51:09 AM

Here is the method

```
         public string CheckCreateOneProjectReportPerDay(string strprojectId)
                {
                    string checkReturnValue = "DoesNotExist";
                    DateTime dtTodaysDate = DateTime.Now;

                    var checkProjectRec =
                        _objContext.tbl_Project_Status_MSTR.Where(
                            s => s.ProjectID == strprojectId && s.StatusDate == dtTodaysDate);

                    if (checkPrjDate.Any())
                    {
                        checkReturnValue = "RecordExist";
                    }

                    return checkReturnValue;
                }
```

I tried to use the keyword contains in the query below  but no luck

```
            var checkProjectRec =
                        _objContext.tbl_Project_Status_MSTR.Where(
                            s => s.ProjectID == strprojectId && s.StatusDate == dtTodaysDate);
```

The query above will always return nothing because they don't match. Is there a better way
of doing this comparison ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your database column StatusDate only stores the Day, Month, and Year of its DateTime object.

I would recommend altering your linq query to search for only those values of dtTodaysDate.

Give this a try:

```
var checkProjectRec =
                    _objContext.tbl_Project_Status_MSTR.Where(
                        s => s.ProjectID == strprojectId 
                            && s.StatusDate.Year == dtTodaysDate.Year
                            && s.StatusDate.Month == dtTodaysDate.Month
                            && s.StatusDate.Day == dtTodaysDate.Day);
```

[Linq-to-SQL: DateTime Methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882657(v=vs.100).aspx) might be worth looking into as well.